# Android - Stopping a periodic service properly

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I would like to know if this is the proper way for stopping my periodically called `service` or not. I have a static boolean variable `isServiceStopped` in my `MainActivity` where I can start or stop the ongoing `service` by clicking on a button. As you see I reschedule my service in the `onDestroy()` method with `AlarmManager`, so if I called `stopService()` in my MainActvity it would just destroy the service but reschedule it again so there would not be any effect. 
This is why I am using a flag, a static boolean variable that I can set in my MainActivity: if I click the button to stop the service I set this flag `true` and the service will not be rescheduled again as it will not run in the `onDestroy()` method.

This is working, but I personally believe that this is just a bad workaround since if I close the app how would the system find the static variable if only the service is running? So what is the proper way doing this? Should I put the reschedule part in the `onStartCommand()`?

Thanks!

```
public class AsyService extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {       
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();               
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {   
            super.onStart(intent, startId); 
         }   

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return START_NOT_STICKY; 
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {  
            //Right now I have a static variable defined in MainActivity to set the boolean isServiceStopped 
            if (!MainActivity.isServiceStopped){
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.set(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 15),
                    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, AsyService.class), 0)
                );
            }

        }

    }
```

**MainAcvitiy:**

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, new Intent(MainActivity.this, AsyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach would be to recreate the original pending intent, cancel it, and remove the service from the Alarm Manager. I dont know why you would want to terminate the service from within itself.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Check for the edited code. I updated my post with the button I want to stop the service with. But it doesn't stop it.

Comment: Is it okay that my reschedule method is in the onDestroy() ?

Comment: @JaniBela: Hi ... very sorry for the late reply ... **YES** it is absolutely correct that you put the reschedule method in `onDestroy()` and *NOT* put it in `onPause()` or anywhere else ... the service will be correctly set when the `Activity` is destroyed